# Efficient way to upload images in SQP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am still very much learning ASP.NET using c# and Webmatrix.  I have put together a photography competition site but can't quite find an ideal way of uploading images.  I don't see the point of uploading images greater than 1200x900 (projectors maximum resolution) so want to make sure images are small as possible.

I am using  tag and checking he image size.  If it's too big I am using 'ImageResizer' to resize the image when saving.  The only way I know to check the size is to convert the  'HttpPostedFileBase' file into an image using System.Drawing.Image.  But when the image is 36Mpixels (it is a photography club)  this is taking an age just to read the height and width properties.  Can I just load the first x bytes to read the properties or do I have to read the whole image?

The second reason I am converting to an image is to extract the exif data.  Again is there an easier and quicker way to read the exif data?

I hope my question makes sense this is all a bit new to me.

simplified code:

```
HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];

using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(uploadedFile.InputStream, true, true))

{

string Exif;

System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

try{

Exif = encoding.GetString(image.GetPropertyItem(36867).Value);

}

catch

{

Exif="";  

}

if (image.Width <Convert.ToInt32(MaxWidth) && image.Height <Convert.ToInt32(MaxHeight))

{

// SAVE IMAGE AS IS

image.Save(fileSavePath);

// LOAD IMAGE DETAILS WITH EXIF

db.Execute("INSERT INTO CompImages (ImageTitle,CompID,GroupID,ClubID,FileName,UserID,ExifDate) VALUES(@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6)",ImageTitle,CompID,GroupID,ClubID,fileName,WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,DateTaken);

}

else           

{

// LOAD IMAGE DETAILS WITH EXIF

db.Execute("INSERT INTO CompImages (ImageTitle,CompID,GroupID,ClubID,FileName,UserID,ExifDate) VALUES(@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6)",ImageTitle,CompID,GroupID,ClubID,fileName,WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,DateTaken);

// RESIZE IMAGE

ImageResizer.ImageJob iF = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(image, "~/UpImages/"+CompID+"/"+fileName, new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings( 
          "width="+MaxWidth+";height="+MaxHeight+";format=jpg;mode=max"));
```

iF.CreateParentDirectory = true; //Auto-create the uploads directory.
  iF.Build();

```
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I know to check the size is to convert the
>   'HttpPostedFileBase' file into an image using System.Drawing.Image.

You could also checkout the [`ContentLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.contentlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property directly:

```
int uploadedFileSize = uploadedFile.ContentLength;
```

> The second reason I am converting to an image is to extract the exif
>   data. Again is there an easier and quicker way to read the exif data?

I am not aware of a built-in class in the BCL that would allow you to read EXIF information without loading the image in memory but you could use some third party library like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET-2-0